# Why maintenance mode doesn't allow my IP?

Tags: magento2, maintenance

I had to put the Magento 2.3.1 in maintenance mode, but I used the command below to allow my domain, I checked in the `var/.maintenance.ip` file and it's correct, but I can't access the store yet.

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=192.0.0.10
```

My `var/.maintenance.flag` is empty and my `var/.maintenance.ip` has this content:

```
192.0.0.10
```

How could allow my IP to access?

Comment: Can you please specify the Magento version?

Comment: Hi @Shankar, I'm using 2.3.1

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right IP address?

Comment: Yes, it's working in other projects

Comment: can you please comment maintenance file after run again command?

Comment: The file just have my ip